# Find numbers in a string

Tags: linux, perl, awk

I have a string

```
string1 = SIZE 15 by 1 ;
```

and

```
string2 = SIZE 3 by 56 ;
```

I am reading these strings from a file line by line in perl and awk
I want to get the numbers in the string like 15 in one variable and 1 in one variable
like wise 3 in one variable and 56 in one variable.

I used $frag1 = substr(line,9,2); $frag2 = substr(line,15,1); in awk which works fine for the first string but fails for the second because the first number in the second string has only one digit.

Any ideas, any regular expressions which I can use. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my ($first, $second) = $string1 =~ /\b(\d+)\b/g;
```

`\b` matches `word boundary` so numbers in strings like `string1` or `1string` will not match.

Comment: Thanks man. It worked like a charm in perl. But I have to also do this on awk. Can you help me out

Comment: awk 'BEGIN{  while(( getline line<"foobar.lef") > 0 ) { if(match(line,"SIZE")){ print line}}' this is what i have till now

Comment: @rozar can't help you with awk

Comment: Thanks. I will figure it out

Answer (score 2):

If your file has lines of the form "string1 = SIZE 15 by 1 ;", you can use the command `awk '{print $4, $6}'`.  If your line is "SIZE 15 by 1" you can just run `awk '{print $2, $4}'`.  No regular expressions are necessary

Answer (score 0):

The regex `(\d+)` should do the trick. You can use the saved variable with `$1`.

And when your string $str is defined like you said with

`my $str = "string1 = SIZE 15 by 1 ;";`

the regex could look like

`/string \d \s = \s SIZE \s (\d+) \s by \s (\d+) \s ;/x`

where the variables `15`and `1` are saved as `$1`and `$2`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Gawk you can take advantage of the extended match() function:

```
if (match($0, /string[0-9]+ = SIZE ([0-9]+) by ([0-9]+)/, a)) {
    print $0 " matches with values " a[1] " and " a[2] "."
}
```